# How does VARIABLE_*_something works? in Yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to build my own yocto_meta-layer based on the imx6ulevk and in  `./meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-sdk/conf/distro/include/fsl-imx-preferred-env.inc` I found something weird:

```
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel_mx6ul = "linux-imx" 
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel_mx6sll = "linux-imx"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel_mx7 = "linux-imx"
```

So i was wondering what does the last *_word (i.e. PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel_*) means?

a) Does it is a way to set a virtual/kernel parser depending on the machine?

b) If [a] is yes, how do i know which name to put? or what part of the machine_name.conf i need to choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PREFERRED_PROVIDER_<recipe-name>_<machine-name>` means this variable applies to mentioned recipe AND the respective `MACHINE` only. This is a common sighting in distro layers. In this particular case, the freescale layer is telling bitbake which Linux kernel recipe to choose depending on the `MACHINE` you either set in `local.conf` or pass via command line. More info [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#bb-bitbake-preferences).

So the answer to a) is yes.

The answer to b) is that you should not bother with changing the `PREFERRED_PROVIDER` for the Linux kernel unless you really know what you're doing (i.e, writing a kernel recipe from scratch). Even if you have a custom board you're unlikely to change the virtual/kernel provider. You'd likely want to follow the BSP maintainer's recommendation. What you need to do is set a proper `MACHINE`, and the `bitbake` will take care of the rest.

For example if your `MACHINE` is `mx6ul`, invoking `bitbake virtual/kernel` is the same as `bitbake linux-imx`. The former is best practice, as you call that in Yocto regardless of the machine.

I'm afraid reading the docs is the best way to fully grasp Yocto. The good thing is that it's documented really well. You'd probably want to start from the [development manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/dev-manual/dev-manual.html) and the bitbake link above, before diving into the mega manual.

Answer (score 1):

The suffix underscore '_' followed by a string means that the variable, PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel in this case is "overridden". bitbake will use this assignment when the OVERRIDES variable contains that particular string, such as "imx6ul".

Many times, if not all, the SoC architecture is set in the MACHINEOVERRIDES variable in the machine.conf, to define what the SoC is on the board. That consequently gets assigned to OVERRIDES in some yocto/bitbake recipe elsewhere.

The Conditional Syntax (Overrides) section in the bitbake manual [1] specifically talks about how this affects the variable expansion.

a.) If we were being strict with the terminology used by Yocto, it would be no. The "machine" per-se correlates to a board, such as "imx6ulevk". The overrides you have there more generally pertain to an SoC architecture (a chip).  You may have many boards running the imx6ul for example. In this case it would pertain to all "machines" running that particular SoC (as defined by your machine in MACHINEOVERRIDES).

b.) Anything appearing in the colon delimited OVERRIDES variable is fair game. You can use the machine name because Yocto does in fact append the MACHINE name to it as well. But it doesn't really make sense to do that because you have a dedication machine.conf file for you to make a hard definition such as PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "something" if you really want a machine/board specific kernel selection.  NXP did this in their distro layer to apply to many machines (aka boards) all at once.

Hint: to see what these variables expand out to, run `bitbake -e virtual/kernel`

These overrides are one of the most powerful features of bitbake. For example if you want to override the source revision of you linux-imx kernel build you can put something like `SRCREV_pn-linux-imx = "something"` in your local.conf. See if you can grep the recipe sources to find out how this works!

References:
[1] https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#conditional-syntax-overrides